# How can i export the header together with the .csv

Tags: python, excel, csv

i wrote a python code to automate a conversion, firstly i get a .pdf, then i covert o a .csv, get the tables i want, and then i convert it to .xlsx. Does anyone know if i can export the headers i have in .csv to the .xlsx file?

here's the .csv file:
[.csv table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I8PP.png)

here's the .xlsx export:
[.xlsx table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r47nE.png)

I'm adding the headers using pandas:

```
def leitor_csv(nome):

dir = r'C:\Users\Arthur\PycharmProjects\Leitor\{}.csv'.format(nome)
df = pd.read_csv(dir, names=['RASTREAMENTO', 'MARCA', 'CLASSE', 'TENSÃO APLICADA', 'CORRENTE FUGA', 'RESULTADO'])

print(df)
```

and i'm converting to .xlsx using globo and pyexcel, here's the code:

```
dir = r'C:\Users\Arthur\PycharmProjects\Leitor\{}.csv'.format(nome)
merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob(dir), f'{nome}.xlsx')
```

obs: please, sorry for my writing, i'm not an english fluent or expert, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the saved csv try using the df you already created.

```
df.to_excel(f'{nome}.xlsx')
```

More info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).